# Google maps API v3, can't get clicked marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm getting from my webAPI an array of json objects of users. I can display the marker for each user correctly in their location but I cannot get to work when I click in each of them to get the clicked item, I always get the information from the last in the list.

This is the code I use to put them on the map:

```
var markers = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var zIndex = membersList[i].type; 
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(membersList[i].latitude,
            membersList[i].longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position' : latLng,
        'shadow' : null,
        'zIndex' : zIndex,
        'title'  : membersList[i].username,
        'id'     : i,
        'icon' : markerImage[membersList[i].type]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    {
        console.log(marker.id);
        var clicked = membersList[marker.id];
        var mType = ['', 'Couple', 'Male', 'Female'];
        var textType = mType[clicked.type];
        var userName = clicked.username;
        $(this).simpledialog2({
            mode: 'button',
            headerText: "OPTIONS",
            headerClose: true,
            buttonPrompt:  userName+ ' ('+textType+')',
            buttons : {
                'PROFILE': {
                    click: function () {
                        toUser = userName;
                        loadPage('profile');
                    },
                    icon: "info"
                },
                'MESSAGE': {
                    click: function () { 
                        toUser = userName;
                        loadPage('compose');
                    },
                    icon: "star",
                }
            }
        });
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
```

By the way I'm using markerClusterer to display the markers grouped on the map in some zoom levels.

Comment: Sounds to me like a closure problem. What does `console.log` line print? A number same as `markers.length`?

Comment: I think that too.. but I tried other ways.. and still got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using marker which is defined outside of you click function.

what you need to look at is the google maps api, and find out how to get the clicked marker id

marker is incrementing through the loop and will ALWAYS be the last marker created

Comment: if that's the case use 'this' instead of 'marker', also try assigning id to the marker, not its options (passed in constructor)

Comment: That worked, Thanks. But it seems really weird, because if you look at google maps api docs: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html you can see how the work fine with closures in the part called "**Using Closures in Event Listeners**"

Comment: The reason it works in the docs it they are calling a separate function to create the event listener, passing in the appropriate marker, thus creating the closure. You are just creating the event listener in the for loop which will always give access to the last marker created. Using this.id instead of marker.id is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It´s never too late, so, if I understood correctly, this is the aproach y would take.

When intantiating the markers, add them to an array after their individual setup is completed.

```
var MySiteWithMap = { 
    markersArray : [], //Markers array
    map : {}, //Map object instance
    init : function() {

       var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
       var mapOptions = {
         center : new google.maps.LatLng(-26.816667, -65.216667),
         zoom : 11
       };
       this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);

       /*
       The following is used to get the Lat and Lng where the user clicks. 
       It may be useful to store the last coordinate where the user clicked.
       */
       this.map.addListener("click", function(event){
          var lat = event.latLng.lat();
          var lng = event.latLng.lng();
          console.log("Lat: "  + lat + "  Lng: "  +  lng);
       });

       MySiteWithMap.initMarkers();

    },
    initMarkers : function(url){
         $.get(url).done(function(result){
            var lat;
            var lng;
            $.each(result,function(index,element){
               lat = element.Latitud;
               lng = element.Longitud;

               var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position : position,
                   map : _this.map,
                   id : element.id //Supposing it's a primary key from the DB or some other unique id.
               });
               marker.addListener('click',function(){
                   console.log(this.id)
               });

               Mapas.markersArray[marker.id] = marker; 
        })
    }
}
```

By doing so, you have an array of Marker objects. If you want to get a reference to an specific marker instance, an option would be to get the id of the clicked marker and look for it on the "markersArray".

If you want to get the position (or any other properties) of a marker, you can do something like this:

```
console.log(MySiteWithMap.markersArray[123].position)
```

Hope this helps!